# search sqlalchemy database for ct_chart

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, bar-chart

I have a database like this:

| name | purchase date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fred | 10/24/2019 | 25.00 |
| wilma | 08/19/2020 | 32.00 |

I am trying to create a ct_chart for my admin page using this data. My database keeps the price and date of each purchase.

My admin panel running with Flask.

What I need is a search query that finds the total amount for the days of the last week. So I can use the daily amount for the chart.

The chart must look like this.

[image]

Comment: Show us the code you're working with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class probably looks like that

```
class Purchase(Base):
    __tablename__ = "purchases"

    id = Column(Int, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    purchase_date = Column(Date)         
    price = Column(Numeric)
```

And the query for the total sum of the purchases:

```
session.query(Purchase.purchase_date, 
func.sum(Table.price)).group_by(
Purchase.purchase_date).filter_by(
Purchase.purchase_date > date.today() - timedelta(days=7)).all()
```

Or for the total purchases:

```
session.query(Purchase.purchase_date, 
func.count(Table.id)).group_by(
Purchase.purchase_date).filter_by(
Purchase.purchase_date > date.today() - timedelta(days=7)).all()
```

imports:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
```